# Persist user theme in localStorage on reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, darkmode

I am building a weather app with React & Tailwind & I am trying to save the users theme preference to local storage but it isn't persisting on reload

Here's my code. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I can set it switching in the storage panel in dev tools and it is saving it there but it isn't setting it to the correct theme on page reload.

```
function App() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  //Call from local Storage
  useEffect(() => {
    const storedPreference = localStorage.getItem('prefersDarkMode');
    if (storedPreference) {
      setDarkMode(JSON.parse(storedPreference));
    }
  }, []);

  //Set to Local Storage
  useEffect(() => {
    if (darkMode) {
      localStorage.setItem('prefersDarkMode', 'true');
      document.body.classList.add('dark');
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('prefersDarkMode', 'false');
      document.body.classList.remove('dark');
    }
  }, [darkMode]);
  return (
    <div className={darkMode ? 'flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-gray-800' : 'bg-neutral-50 flex flex-col min-h-screen'}>
      <Header>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setDarkMode(!darkMode);
          }}
        >
          {darkMode ? <BsFillSunFill className="fill-neutral-100 text-2xl" /> : <BsFillMoonFill className="fill-gray-700 text-2xl" />}
        </button>
      </Header>
      <ToastContainer theme={darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light'} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please do not use ifs on booleans `useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('prefersDarkMode', darkMode);
      document.body.classList.toggle('dark',darkMode);
  }, [darkMode]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I have seen in your codes is ..

the other useEffect initially calls the localStorage for **prefersDarkMode**

and the other one is for changing the **darkmode** state and setting the localStorage

when you reload the page, the darkmode state is always false, because of this

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (darkMode) {
    localStorage.setItem('prefersDarkMode', 'true');
    document.body.classList.add('dark');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('prefersDarkMode', 'false');
    document.body.classList.remove('dark');
  }
}, [darkMode]);
```

this useEffect will set the **prefersDarkMode** in your localStorage to false every time you reload

to fix this, i added another state to check if the app already call the localStorage

```
const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

 //Call from local Storage
 useEffect(() => {
   const storedPreference = localStorage.getItem("prefersDarkMode");
   if (storedPreference) {
     setDarkMode(JSON.parse(storedPreference));
   }
   setFlag(true);
 }, []);

 //Set to Local Storage
 useEffect(() => {
   if (flag) {
     localStorage.setItem("prefersDarkMode", darkMode);
     document.body.classList.toggle('dark',darkMode)
   }
 }, [darkMode, flag]);
```

so that, it won't set it back to default on reload

here is the working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-nash-6fu3c5

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem. Changed the if/else blocks to a ternary to clean things up (thanks to @jigolka for that tip).

Answer (score 1):

Here what you can improve/try:

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("prefersDarkMode", darkMode ? "true" : "false");

    darkMode
      ? document.body.classList.add("dark")
      : document.body.classList.remove("dark");
  }, [darkMode]);
```

```
<button
     onClick={() => {
        setDarkMode((previousState) => !previousState);
      }}>
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: Thank you. This helped and cleaned up my code considerably.